# Div positioning|| Why does margin: property doesn't work yet the left: works?

Tags: html, css, css-position, positioning

EDIT: Thanks for the explanations on position, as I said I'm just trying to figure it out why margin was not working and the position:left was.
So from what I understood, basically you can only position using margins for static elements, anything else you have to use position:x . Right?

I'm pretty sure this is something incredibly basic, but I've just started out learning positioning, and I was tinkering with the tutorial code ,and I can't seem to grasp the way these div inner div is behaving.

According to what I've been reading shouldn't this code make the inner box margin move relatively to the body, since there's no parent element with absolute position? If I use the "left:" property instead of "margin:" it does exactly that.

To clarify, I'm just trying to understand why is #inner being positioned relative to #outer regardless of the position value assigned to #outer.

```css
div {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#inner {
  height: 75px;
  width: 75px;
  background-color: #547980;
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

#outer {
  height: 1500px;
  width: 150px;
  background-color: #45ADA8;
  position: static;
  margin-left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="outer">
  <div id="inner"></div>
</div>
```

Result Image

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The position Property

The `position` property specifies the type of **positioning** method used for an element.

There are **four** different `position` values:

```
static

relative

fixed

absolute
```

**[How Do They Differ?](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)**

**1.** if you are using `static`.
HTML elements are positioned static by default.

`Static` positioned elements are not affected by the `top`, `bottom`, `left`, and `right` properties.

```css
.static {
  position: static;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
```

```html
<div class="static">Hello i m static position </div>
```

**2.** if you are using `relative`.

Setting the `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties of a relatively-positioned element will cause it to be adjusted away from its normal position.

```css
.relative1 {
  position: relative;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
.relative2 {
  position: relative;
  top: -20px;
  left: 20px;
  background-color: white;
  width: 500px;
  border:solid 1px black;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative1"> hi i m Relative 1</div>
<div class="relative2">hi i m Relative 2</div>
```

**3.** if you are using `fixed`.

An element with `position: fixed;` is positioned `relative` to the viewport, which means it always stays in the same place even if the page is scrolled. The `top`, `right`, `bottom`, and `left` properties are used to position the element.

A `fixed` element does not leave a gap in the page where it would normally have been located.

```css
.fixed {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="fixed">HI i m fixed div </div>
```

**4.** if you are using `absolute` with `relative`.

`absolute` is the trickiest position value. `absolute` behaves like `fixed` except relative to the nearest positioned ancestor instead of `relative` to the viewport. If an absolutely-positioned element has no positioned ancestors, it uses the document `body`, and still moves along with page scrolling. Remember, a "positioned" element is one whose position is anything except `static`.

```css
.relative {
  position: relative;
  width: 600px;
  height: 400px;
  border:solid 1px red;
}
.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  top: 120px;
  right: 0;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  border:solid 1px gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="relative">
<div class="absolute"> I  m Absolute div </div>
</div>
```

**[Source by](http://learnlayout.com/position.html)**

Comment: Thanks for the explanations on position, as I said I'm just trying to figure it out why margin was not working and the position:left was. So from what I understood, basically you can only position using margins for static elements, anything else you have to use position:x . Right?

Comment: @TylerC if you using absolute position than used to top, left, right, bottom it's better to margin .

Comment: @TylerC if you are using absolute position than it's take margin to window not the your body or div .  If you used to relative than absolute means used to parent div relative than used to child absolute than it's take to margin or top position it's parents div please refer to my example for better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you didn't give top/left value to your absolute div.

Give left position will behave like absolute position.

```
#inner {
    height: 75px;
    width: 75px;
    background-color: #547980;
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 20px;
  left:10px;
}
```

**[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/yacL4e3p/)**

If your absolute div have top/bottom and left/right are auto then it will behave like static position.

You can check more details **[here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-width)**.